# C++ function parent

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a bunch of functions that all have the same basic function but 1 part is different.  Something like

```
returnType1 doSomething1(param1) {
    if (_api== nullptr) throw exceptionNotConnected();
    try {
        return doSomething1Inner(param1); //always returns same type as main function but not all inners return same as each other
    } catch(DigiByteException &e) {
        if (e.getMessage()!="Failed to authenticate successfully") {
            throw exceptionOffline();
        }
        throw exception(e.getMessage());
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        throw exception();
    }
}
```

is there any way I can write this once than do something like

```
returnType1 doSomething1(param1) {
    errorCheck(doSomething1Inner(param1));
}
```

Or some other format.  I just want to be able to make this easily maintainable for having the same wrapper code around each function hundreds of times.  If it's not possible cut and past will work.

Comment: Can you provide an actual example?

Comment: Other than I made the function name generic it is an actual example.  I am wrapping an API library so I have hundreds of little functions that have the same error handling functions around the api call.  I could cut and past but that wouldn't be very easily maintainable and figured there must be a better way.

Comment: What's wrong with doing "something like" checking what is returned by a function?     In any event, your example is too contrived (e.g.  falling off the end, causing undefined behaviour, if the inner function returns rather than throws).    You need to provide an example of what you are ACTUALLY trying to achieve.

Comment: I see the problem.  I accidently removed the return while changing the function name of inner function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do almost the same as @Miles. However I would do lambdas do the lifting of parameter capture.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

struct DigiByteException
{
    std::string getMessage()
    {
        return {};
    }
};

struct OfflineException
{
};

int test()
{
    return 42;
}

struct TestClass
{
    void do_something() {};
};

template <typename fn_t>
auto call_with_error_check(fn_t fn)
{
    if (_api == nullptr)
    {
        throw OfflineException();
    }

    try
    {
        return fn();
    }
    catch (DigiByteException& e)
    {
        if (e.getMessage() != "Failed to authenticate successfully") // <== By the way NEVER do this. Text should not be an used to identify an error
        {
            throw OfflineException();
        }
        throw std::runtime_error{ e.getMessage() };
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

int main()
{
    TestClass c;
    auto value = call_with_error_check(test);
    call_with_error_check([&] {c.do_something(); });

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is actually the more versatile answer since it allows functions that have 0 to infinite args where first answer is 1 to infinite args.  It is also easier to read code.  Thanks both for the lesson.

Comment: If forgot to mention : you will also be able to capture variables in the way you choose (copy or reference)

Answer (score 5):

You can create a wrapper function template that you pass the wrapped function to along with any arguments:

```
template <typename InnerFn, typename... Args>
auto errorCheck(InnerFn&& innerFn, Args&&... args)
    -> decltype(innerFn(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
    if (_api== nullptr) throw exceptionNotConnected();
    try {
        return innerFn(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    } catch(DigiByteException &e) {
        if (e.getMessage()!="Failed to authenticate successfully") {
            throw exceptionOffline();
        }
        throw exception(e.getMessage());
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        throw exception();
    }
}

returnType1 doSomething1(ArgType param1)
{
    return errorCheck(doSomethingInner, param1);
}
```

Comment: I get a note that the first auto is only valid in C++14 is there any way to do in c++11?

Comment: Edited.  You can add a trailing return type.  It's a little redundant, but it works.

Comment: thank you so much this works well and will be a very helpful trick to know going forward.